# How to Group dictionary values in python and subtotal

Tags: python, django, pandas, numpy, dictionary

I have the following dictionary

```py
#BEFORE
data={
'cell_1':['13a'], 'jam_1': ['07-08'], 'model_1': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_1': ['10'], 'output_jam_1': [''], 'time_1': [''], 'output_ot_1': [''], 'time_ot_1': [''],
'cell_2':['13a'], 'jam_2': ['07-08'], 'model_2': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_2': ['20'], 'output_jam_2': [''], 'time_2': [''], 'output_ot_2': [''], 'time_ot_2': [''], 
'cell_3':['13c'], 'jam_3': ['07-08'], 'model_3': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_3': ['40'], 'output_jam_3': [''], 'time_3': [''], 'output_ot_3': [''], 'time_ot_3': [''], 
'cell_4':['13b'], 'jam_4': ['08-09'], 'model_4': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_4': ['30'], 'output_jam_4': [''], 'time_4': [''], 'output_ot_4': [''], 'time_ot_4': [''],
'cell_5':['13d'], 'jam_5': ['16-17'], 'model_5': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_5': ['40'], 'output_jam_5': [''], 'time_5': [''], 'output_ot_5': [''], 'time_ot_5': [''],
'cell_6':['13d'], 'jam_6': ['16-17'], 'model_6': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_6': ['40'], 'output_jam_6': [''], 'time_6': [''], 'output_ot_6': [''], 'time_ot_6': [''],
'cell_7':['13d'], 'jam_7': ['17-18'], 'model_7': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_7': ['10'], 'output_jam_7': [''], 'time_7': [''], 'output_ot_7': [''], 'time_ot_7': [''],
'cell_8':['13d'], 'jam_8': ['18-19'], 'model_8': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_8': ['60'], 'output_jam_8': [''], 'time_8': [''], 'output_ot_8': [''], 'time_ot_8': [''],
}
I WANT
#AFTER
data={
'cell_1':['13a'], 'jam_1': ['07-08'], 'model_1': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_1': ['10'], 'output_jam_1': ['30'], 'time_1': ['0.33'], 'output_ot_1': [''], 'time_ot_1':[''],
'cell_2':['13a'], 'jam_2': ['07-08'], 'model_2': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_2': ['20'], 'output_jam_2': ['30'], 'time_2': ['0.67'], 'output_ot_2': [''], 'time_ot_2':[''],
'cell_3':['13c'], 'jam_3': ['07-08'], 'model_3': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_3': ['40'], 'output_jam_3': ['40'], 'time_3': ['1'], 'output_ot_3': [''], 'time_ot_3':[''],
'cell_4':['13b'], 'jam_4': ['08-09'], 'model_4': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_4': ['30'], 'output_jam_4': ['30'], 'time_4': ['1'], 'output_ot_4': [''], 'time_ot_4':[''],
'cell_5':['13d'], 'jam_5': ['16-17'], 'model_5': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_5': ['40'], 'output_jam_5': [''], 'time_5': [''], 'output_ot_5': ['80'], 'time_ot_5':['0.5'],
'cell_6':['13d'], 'jam_6': ['16-17'], 'model_6': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_6': ['40'], 'output_jam_6': [''], 'time_6': [''], 'output_ot_6': ['80'], 'time_ot_6':['0.5'],
'cell_7':['13d'], 'jam_7': ['17-18'], 'model_7': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_7': ['10'], 'output_jam_7': [''], 'time_7': [''], 'output_ot_7': ['10'], 'time_ot_7':['1'],
'cell_8':['13d'], 'jam_8': ['18-19'], 'model_8': ['SUPERSTAR'], 'output_8': ['60'], 'output_jam_8': [''], 'time_8': [''], 'output_ot_8': ['60'], 'time_ot_8':['1'],
}
```

1. How can I obtain the sum of the key 'output' for every dictionary values '07-08' '08-09' and values 13a, 13b, 13c, 13d in the list of dictionaries and then I want to insert that to 'output_jam'.
2. How can I obtain the sum of the key 'output' for every dictionary values '16-17', '17-18', '18-19' in the list of dictionaries and then I want to insert that to 'output_ot'.
3. How can I calculate 'time' using formula (time = output / output jam).
4. How can I obtain the calculate 'time_ot' using formula (time_ot = output /output_ot)

Could you please have your suggestions on this??

Comment: I'd recommend reforming the data into something more sane. If you're familiar with pandas you could try to force it into a dataframe

Comment: Your questions are phrased in a confusing way. By no.2, don't you mean output_jam? And you should rephrase no.1, its only about the jam values and nothing to do with the cell values correct?

Comment: you should convert it to list with dictionaries and then you could have variables without numbers - `[{"cell": ... }, {"cell": ... }, ...]` - and then it is easier to make your calculations.

Comment: With the data structure you currently have, it's hard to do the operations you want to. So it comes with no surprise, that you have a hard time with that. I am also not sure, if you can rely on the order of the keys beeing preserved, because I think usual dictionaries don't guarantee that in Python (there is something called an OrderedDictionary).

Answer (score 0):

What we meant by using another data structure was, that if you for example store your data in a list like below, it's much easier to perform the operations you ask for. Please note, that I removed the lists around the values and use an int to represent the value of `output`.

```
data=[
{'cell': '13a', 'jam': '07-08', 'model': 'SUPERSTAR', 'output': 10, 'output_jam': '30', 'time': '0.33', 'output_ot': '', 'time_ot': ''},
{'cell': '13a', 'jam': '07-08', 'model': 'SUPERSTAR', 'output': 20, 'output_jam': '30', 'time': '0.67', 'output_ot': '', 'time_ot': ''},
{'cell': '13c', 'jam': '07-08', 'model': 'SUPERSTAR', 'output': 40, 'output_jam': '40', 'time': '1', 'output_ot': '', 'time_ot': ''},
{'cell': '13b', 'jam': '08-09', 'model': 'SUPERSTAR', 'output': 30, 'output_jam': '30', 'time': '1', 'output_ot': '', 'time_ot': ''},
{'cell': '13d', 'jam': '16-17', 'model': 'SUPERSTAR', 'output': 40, 'output_jam': '', 'time': '', 'output_ot': '80', 'time_ot': '0.5'},
{'cell': '13d', 'jam': '16-17', 'model': 'SUPERSTAR', 'output': 40, 'output_jam': '', 'time': '', 'output_ot': '80', 'time_ot': '0.5'},
{'cell': '13d', 'jam': '17-18', 'model': 'SUPERSTAR', 'output': 10, 'output_jam': '', 'time': '', 'output_ot': '10', 'time_ot': '1'},
{'cell': '13d', 'jam': '18-19', 'model': 'SUPERSTAR', 'output': 60, 'output_jam': '', 'time': '', 'output_ot': '60', 'time_ot': '1'}]
```

On that structure, you could implement your filtering and grouping operations easier.
E.g. filtering all dictionaries whose `jam` key is one of `'07-08', '08-09'` just can be done like this:

```
filtered= [doc for doc in data if doc['jam'] in ['07-08', '08-09']]
```

Really simple, isn't it?

For the grouping (the sums for the dictionaries with the same `jam` value), you can use itertools.groupby:

```
from itertools import groupby

def sort_and_groupby(data, key):
    data.sort(key=key)
    return groupby(data, key=key)

for key, grouper in sort_and_groupby(data, lambda doc: doc['jam']):
    print(key, sum(map(lambda doc: doc['output'], grouper)))
```

You just have to make sure, the data is presorted if you use `itertools.groupby`, otherwise the data is not aggregated properly. This is why I defined `sort_and_groupby`. It just returns a groupby object. The groupby object allows to iterate over all distinct values for jam and for each of them it returns a grouper, that is itself an iterator that iterates over all dictionary with that value. Finally with `map(lambda...` I extract all values stored for key `output` in those dictionary and sum it up.

But as already somone else stated, you could also do that in pandas. With pandas such things become much easier. But that all depens on whether you can change your data structure, or if it is fixed somehow.